# Startup POJO On A Weld/Seam3 Application

Tags: java, seam, cdi, jboss-weld, seam3

I'm trying to get a POJO starting on startup within my Weld/Seam3 application but not having much luck.  I've tried the following but none of them have worked:

```
@Singleton
public class StartupJobs {
    @Inject
    private Logger log;

    public void onStartup(@Observes @Initialized ServletContextEvent event) {
        log.info("Starting startup jobs");
    }

    public void onStartupTwo(@Observes @Initialized WebApplication webApplication) {
        log.info("Starting startup jobs");
    }
}
```

-

```
// Guessing this way is no good as I can't use the javax.ejb.Startup annotation here
@ApplicationScoped
public class StartupJobs {
    @Inject
    private Logger log;

    @PostConstruct
    public void onStartup() {
        log.info("Starting startup jobs");
    }
}
```

But neither of those ways worked.  My log message was never raised.  As this application is run on Tomcat6 and I've had to add the "org.jboss.weld.environment.servlet.Listener" listener to my web.xml, I'm wondering if there's something that class raises that I could observe.  I didn't notice anything in particular though.

Any clue what else I could try?

Comment: Not directly related to the question, but `JBoss 7` is really fast and it is a `JEE` container. Using a plain servlet container like `Tomcat` is begging for configuration problems.

Comment: @Petar You're right. The move to something like JBoss AS would help things. But that's a company decision so I'm stuck with Tomcat for now!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found out my issue was configuration. I hadn't seen I needed some extra configuration due to being on Tomcat 6: http://docs.jboss.org/seam/3/servlet/latest/reference/en-US/html/servlet-installation.html#installation.pre-servlet-3

A quick note on the documentation on that page as it stands as I write this, the class for the "Catch Exception Filter" should be "org.jboss.seam.servlet.exception.CatchExceptionFilter".  The documentation is missing out the "exception". It seems to have been fixed in the Seam Servlet code so I imagine this bug will be fixed next time the documentation is released.