# How to configure a start up managed bean?

Tags: jsf, startup, managed-bean

I want a managed bean to run internally on start up in my JSF web application when the application loads. How can I write this class and configure in Glassfish?

Comment: Have you tried `@ManagedBean(eager=true)` ? 

If you are using CDI (@Named instead of @ManagedBean) then you would have to "Observe" app initialization.. with something like this...

`public void init(@Observes @Initialized WebApplication webApplication) { //do Something }`

(actually I have not tried this in glassfish, I have used it in jBoss AS 7 and you might need some configuration on other servers...check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7347516/startup-pojo-on-a-weld-seam3-application) out...

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In JSF with CDI, [observe](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/enterprise/event/Observes.html) the [initialization](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/enterprise/context/Initialized.html) of the [application scope](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/enterprise/context/ApplicationScoped.html).

```
@Named
@ApplicationScoped
public class App {

    public void startup(@Observes @Initialized(ApplicationScoped.class) Object context) {
        // ...
    }

    public void shutdown(@Observes @Destroyed(ApplicationScoped.class) Object context) {
        // ...
    }

}
```

When having [OmniFaces](http://omnifaces.org) at hands, this can be simplified with [`@Eager`](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/cdi/Eager).

```
@Named
@Eager
@ApplicationScoped
public class App {

    @PostConstruct
    public void startup() {
        // ...
    }

    @PreDestroy
    public void shutdown() {
        // ...
    }
}
```

In JSF 2.2- with the [now deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4347374/backing-beans-managedbean-or-cdi-beans-named) `javax.faces.bean` annotations, use an [application scoped](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/faces/bean/ApplicationScoped.html) [managed bean](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/faces/bean/ManagedBean.html) which is [eagerly](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/faces/bean/ManagedBean.html#eager--) initialized.

```
@ManagedBean(eager=true)
@ApplicationScoped
public class App {

    @PostConstruct
    public void startup() {
        // ...
    }

    @PreDestroy
    public void shutdown() {
        // ...
    }
}
```