# JSF application onload configuration

Tags: jsf, onload, method-call

Any configuration available in JSF to call some function on "Application on-load" ?
as we have load-on-startup in web.xml.

Thanks.

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3600534/jsf-how-do-i-force-an-application-scoped-bean-to-instantiate-at-application-st

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to configure a start up class in glassfish server?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11474882/how-to-configure-a-start-up-class-in-glassfish-server)